# Count value in column if another column = True

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Basically, here is what I need a working formula for:

If cell C1:C25 is `"True"` and cell A1:A25 is `Y` then add `1` to D1
If cell C1:C25 is `"True"` and cell A1:A25 is `N` then add `0.5` to D1
If cell C1:C25 is `"False"` add nothing to D1

Answer (score 1):

### if column C is text-based like:

- **`=T("TRUE")`**
- **`="TRUE"`**
- **`=TEXT("TRUE"; "@")`**
- **`=TEXT(TRUE; "@")`**

  - **paste this formula where you need so and drag down the blue square to reach 25th row**

```
=IF(AND(C1="TRUE" ; A1="Y"); D1+1; 
 IF(AND(C1="TRUE" ; A1="N"); D1+0.5;
 IF(    C1="FALSE";          D1; )))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

### if column C is [boolean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type)-based like:

- **`=TRUE`**
- **`TRUE`**
- **`=ISNUMBER(x)`**
- **`=ISTEXT(TRUE)`**

  - **paste this formula where you need so and drag down the blue square to reach 25th row**

```
=IF(AND(C1=TRUE; A1="Y"); D1+1; 
 IF(AND(C1=TRUE; A1="N"); D1+0.5;
 IF(ISBLANK(C1)=FALSE;    D1; )))
```

[image: 5]